# Find the remainder when $2^{47}$ is divided by $47$

Tags: number-theory

So I am trying to work out how to find remainders in several different way.

I have a few very similar question,

1.) Find the remainder when $2^{47}$ is divided by 47

So i have a solution that says 
$$2^{24} \equiv 2$$

$$2^{48} \equiv 4$$
$$2^{47} \equiv 2$$ Since $(2,47)=1$

and

2.)Find the remainder when $2^{32}$ is divided by $47$:

We have $$2^6 = 64 \equiv 17$$
$$2^{12} \equiv 17^2 = 289 \equiv 7$$
$$2^{24} \equiv 7^2=49  \equiv 2$$
$$2^8 \equiv 4*17=68  \equiv 21$$
$$2^{32}=2^{8}*2^{24}  \equiv21*2 \equiv42$$

Okay so although i have some solutions here, Im not 100 percent sure how they derived this. For example on the second question, why have they started with $2^{6}$ before finding the remainder? Is there some steps missing or am I just missing the point?

Is this called something in particular? There are not many problems similar to and i do not know if it has a special name to search for.

P.S Please do not use fermat's little theorem, i want to understand this method, thanks :)

Comment: No!! it is 1!! sorry :)

Comment: The line "$12^{12}\equiv17^2=289\equiv7$" has a typo; that $12^{12}$ should read $2^{12}$; this line is obtained by squaring both sides of $2^6\equiv17$. Another typo one line below that, "$7^2=499$", that should be $49$.

Comment: $\large 2\ ?$.   Two ?.

Comment: I have the sol as $2^{24} \equiv 7^2 = 499 \equiv 2$ and yes the 12 should be a 2!

Comment: is this meant to be 49? I was thinking that seems odd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Find the remainder when $2^{47}$ is divided by $47$.

$2^1\equiv2\pmod{47}$

$2^2\equiv4\pmod{47}$

$2^4\equiv16\pmod{47}$

$2^8=(2^4)^2\equiv(16)^2=256\equiv21\pmod{47}$

$2^{16}=(2^8)^2\equiv(21)^2=441\equiv18\pmod{47}$

$2^{24}=2^8\cdot2^{16}\equiv21\cdot18=378\equiv2\pmod{47}$

$2^{48}\equiv2^2=4\pmod{47}$

$2*2^{47}\equiv2*2\pmod{47}$

Since $ca\equiv cb\pmod m$ and $(c,m)=1$ implies $a\equiv b\pmod m$, and since $(2,47)=1$, we can cancel the $2$:

$2^{47}\equiv2\pmod{47}$

2) Find the remainder when $2^{32}$ is divided by $47$.

From the previous solution:

$2^{24}\equiv2\pmod{47}$

$2^8\equiv21\pmod{47}$

$2^{32}=2^{24+8}=2^{24}\cdot2^8\equiv2\cdot21=42\pmod{47}$

Answer (score 2):

[Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) gives you the answer at once: since $\;47\; $ is prime, we get

$$2^{47}=2\pmod {47}$$

which means that the wanted residue is $\;2\;$ .

Comment: I just made the same mistake. Read the last line :-)

Comment: (He asked specifically for "not Fermat's Little Theorem")

Comment: Thank you! I know about fermats little theorem but i wanted to use an alternative method as my exam may ask m to solve it without fermats.. Thank you though :)

Comment: Ha sorry guys my bad should have put it at the top. Many thanks though :)

Comment: No @DennisMeng, he wrote that in problem number two, not number one.

Comment: I meant it for both problems...

Comment: It is a quite nice result. Fermat always Fermat.

Comment: It is much nicer indeed but i do need to know both methods and the one i was asking about it very hard to find anything about it, unlike fermats :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this constitutes a full answer, but I cannot leave comments yet.

Notice that $2^5 = 32 < 47$, and $2^6 = 64 > 47$.  That is, we are starting with the first power of $2$ that is greater than the number we're dividing by.  If the number were less, the remainder would simply be the number we started with.

As for a term, try looking at Modular Arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks for this, i thought that may be the case but wasnt 100% sure. so for the line $$12^{12} \equiv 17^2 = 289 \equiv 7$$, how did they know that $12^{12} \equiv 17^2$? is there a way of working this out

Comment: On the previous step we showed that $12^6 \equiv 17$, and $12^{12} = (12^6)^2 \equiv 17^2 = 289$.  The last part is the remainder of $289/47$, which is $7$.

Comment: okay great thanks! And is the 499 meant to be 49? Im confused as i have found this solution so is it an error?

Comment: Actually there are a few typos, some of which I've just propagated!  Let me try to clear up what I previously wrote.  We showed that $2^6 \equiv 17$ and $2^{12} = (2^6)^2 \equiv 17^2$.  That $12$ should be a $2$, and the $499$ should be a $49$.  I think one of the comments further up notes this as well.

Comment: I did edit this did it not change it? It is changed on my screen... Thanks though!! I was confused about the 49...

Answer (score 1):

The following method is called the [Right-to-Left Binary Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) on Wikipedia. Generally, it reduces the number of operations needed for modular exponentiation. The method works by considering the exponent in binary, where multiplying the exponent by two (shifting left in binary) corresponds to squaring, and adding one to the exponent corresponds to multiplying by the base.

$47=101111_\text{two}$ so we get
$$
\begin{align}
2^{0_\text{two}}&\equiv1\pmod{47}\\
2^{1_\text{two}}&\equiv2\pmod{47}\tag{square and multiply by 2}\\
2^{10_\text{two}}&\equiv4\pmod{47}\tag{square}\\
2^{101_\text{two}}&\equiv32\pmod{47}\tag{square and multiply by 2}\\
2^{1011_\text{two}}&\equiv27\pmod{47}\tag{square and multiply by 2}\\
2^{10111_\text{two}}&\equiv1\pmod{47}\tag{square and multiply by 2}\\
2^{101111_\text{two}}&\equiv2\pmod{47}\tag{square and multiply by 2}\\
\end{align}
$$
$32=100000_\text{two}$ so we get
$$
\begin{align}
2^{0_\text{two}}&\equiv1\pmod{47}\\
2^{1_\text{two}}&\equiv2\pmod{47}\tag{square and multiply by 2}\\
2^{10_\text{two}}&\equiv4\pmod{47}\tag{square}\\
2^{100_\text{two}}&\equiv16\pmod{47}\tag{square}\\
2^{1000_\text{two}}&\equiv21\pmod{47}\tag{square}\\
2^{10000_\text{two}}&\equiv18\pmod{47}\tag{square}\\
2^{100000_\text{two}}&\equiv42\pmod{47}\tag{square}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you! I have not used this notation before does it mean the same thing as in my question sol?

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews: you mean [base-two numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number)? It is easier to see what is going on when doing [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) when the exponent is written in binary.