# Does the least positive multiple $10^n-1$ of prime $p$ divide $10^{p-1}-1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime other than $2$ or $5$. Let $n$ be the least positive integer with $10^n\equiv 1\pmod p$. By Fermat's Little Theorem, $n\leq p - 1$.

Does $10^n-1$ divide $10^{p-1}-1$?

I think so. Maybe looking at Euclid's algorithm for the greatest common divisor of $10^n-1$ and $10^{p-1}-1$ would help?

You see, I aim to provide answers the following week to challenges that I pose on my whiteboard. I posed two problems as fun challenges on my whiteboard last week.

The first problem was the special case $p=71$ for which $n=35$ and, behold, $(10^{35}-1)(10^{35}+1)+1 = 10^{70}$. Besides, with patience or a big-number calculator we easily see that the decimal expansion of $1/71$ repeats every $35$ digits.

The second problem was the general case, to state an efficient algorithm to find $n$ as defined above for any prime $p$. I asked because I expected the answer would immediately be clear to me. Oops!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $\,{\rm mod}\,\ p\!:\,\, $ if $\, {\rm ord}_p(10) = n\,$ then $\, 10^k\equiv 1\iff n\mid k.\,$

Here is one way to prove this. First, notice that $\color{#c00}{10^n\equiv 1\equiv 10^k}\Rightarrow 10^{(n,k)}\!\equiv1\,$ since by Bezout's gcd identity $\,(n,k) = ni+kj\ $ so $\,10^{(n,k)}\! = 10^{\,ni+kj}\! = (\color{#c00}{10^n})^i (\color{#c00}{10^k})^j \equiv \color{#c00}1^i \color{#c00}1^j \equiv 1.$

Hence if $\,n\nmid k\,$ then $\,(n,k) < n\,$ and $\,10^{(n,k)}\!\equiv 1,\,$ contra minimality of $\,n := {\rm ord}_p(10).\ \, $ **QED**

The **key idea** of the proof: $ $ the set $\,S\,$ of naturals $\,k> 0\,$ such that $10^k\equiv 1\,$ are closed under $\,\rm gcd,\,$ therefore its least element $\,n\,$ must divide every element $\,k\in S\ $ (else their gcd $\,(n,k)\,$ would, by hypothesis,  be an element of $\,S,\,$ but smaller than the least element $\,n).$

Comment: Oh good, apparently I had an inkling of the key idea! Hate to be obtuse, but I'll have to reserve some time to read the rest carefully.

Comment: @ajm475du Yes, you were on the right track. In fact any set $S$ of naturals $> 0$ that are closed under subtraction $(> 0)$ are also closed under mod, so also closed under gcd, so the least element divides all other elements (this is how the Euclidean gcd algorithm works). The algebraic structure at the heart of this will become clearer when one studies *ideals*, PIDs and Euclidean domains in abstract algebra.

Comment: I am slipping. You used Bezout and I didn't.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** This follows from the fact that $n$ divides $p-1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  $(a^n-1) \mid (a^{mn}-1)$  for $1<a,m,n \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: OK, that generalizes an easy observation that $10^6-1=999,999=(999)1,001=(10^3-1)((10^3)^2-1)/(10^3-1)$. Not sure what this looks like if you reckon with lakh and crore, presumably the same. But I have to look at proving the fact from @andre-nicolas though.

Comment: It is equivalent to @andre-nicolas' hint

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n$ is the least positive integer so that $10^n\equiv1\pmod{p}$. Let
$$
p-1=qn+r
$$
where $0\le r\lt n$. Since $(p,10)=1$, $10$ is invertible mod $p$ and therefore,
$$
10^r\equiv10^{p-1-qn}\equiv1\pmod{p}
$$
Since $n$ is the least positive integer so that $10^n\equiv1\pmod{p}$, and $r\lt n$, we must have that $r=0$; that is, $p-1=qn$. Thus,
$$
10^n-1\mid10^{p-1}-1
$$
Since $10^{p-1}-1=10^{qn}-1=(10^n-1)(1+10^n+10^{2n}+\dots+10^{(q-1)n})$

---

For the general question, we know that $n\mid p-1$, and computing $10^n$ mod $p$ is fairly easy using the [Right to Left Binary Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) illustrated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/538984) so an educated brute force attack should not be too difficult.